# listener can not start

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, listener

My listener in Oracle 11g R2 can not start . When I want to give the status of that, the error in below is shown:

```
Connecting to <ADDRESS=<PROTOCOL=tcp><HODT=><PORT=1521>>
TNS-12541 : TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560 : TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511 : NO LISTENER 
   64-bit Windowns Eroor : 61: Wnknown error
```

My `tnsnames.ora` is :

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\SHOJAIE\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SHOJAIE-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

My `listener.ora` is :

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\SHOJAIE\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\SHOJAIE\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\SHOJAIE\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = SHOJAIE-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = D:\app\SHOJAIE
```

Can any one help me ?

Comment: Looks like you've installed some Quest software that's messed with your paths. What is %ORACLE_HOME% set to! and is it at the beginning of your PATH?

Comment: set ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\SHOJAIE\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1

Comment: but my quest software in C:\program files <x86>\Quest

Comment: What is `%TNS_ADMIN%` set to?

Answer (score 1):

Try to Restart Oracle Service by following Commands

```
net stop oracleserviceORCL;
net start oracleserviceORCL;
```

and then start listener first, if it is not already started by this command.

```
lsnrctl start listener;
```

and update me if it help...

Comment: when i write this command , the error in below is shown :         TNS-12560 : TNS:protocol adapter error                                    TNS-00530 : Protocl adapter error

Comment: what error are you getting when you ping ORCL, like:
`SQL> tnsping ORCL;`

Comment: @saeed - Check answer updates.

Comment: when i write netca in command prompt , i dont see any listener to configure and when i want to add , some of error is occured like : TNS - 04415 : file i/o error caused by :java.io.FileNotException : C:\Program files <x86>\common Files \ Quest Shared \ instantclient-basic-win-x86-11.2.0.1.0\listener.ora <access is denied >

Comment: open `CMD` with `Administrator` and the execute `netca` command,
or
goto `start>all progrram>oracle > configuration and migration > Oracle Configuration Assistance` and right click and select 'run as administrator' and try to create listener

Comment: when i write tnsname orcl , the error of below is shown :

Comment: used parameter files:C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Quest Shared\instantclient-basic-win-x86-64-11.2.0.1.0\sqlnet.ora     TNS-03505 : FAILED TO RESOLVE NAME

Comment: check database service from `netmgr`,
if you don't find `ORCL` service, just create from netmgr

Comment: or directly goto the `sqlnet.ora` file, copy-paste existing entry and change it relevant to your `ORCL` instance.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12726/discussion-between-nikhil-butani-and-saeed-sh)

Comment: ok , where can we chat ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried to start the listener via console:

```
> lsnrctl star
```

This command printed the following error:

```
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
TNS-00583: Valid node checking: unable to parse configuration parameters
```

So, I performed the following actions:

1. Check if Oracle `listener.ora` or `sqlnet.ora` file contains special characters
2. Check if Oracle `listener.ora` or sqlnet.ora` file are in wrong format or syntax
3. Check if Oracle `listener.ora` or `sqlnet.ora` file have some left justified parenthesis which are not accepted by oracle parser.

Have a look at these files and check the proper syntax. If possible remove/rename sqlnet.ora and try to restart the listener. Or remove/rename both listener.ora or sqlnet.ora file and recreate it properly. These will defenitely resolve the issue.